# React/NextJS Timer-based fade in/fade out of text not working

Tags: reactjs, next.js, css-animations

I'm relatively new to React and NextJS. I've spent a good 8 hours and a fair amount of research trying to figure this out with no luck!

I'm trying to set up a component that picks a word at random from an array, fades this in, then after a delay fades it out and fades in a new word.

After hacking together several of my own failed solutions, I found a tutorial and tried their code (with some changes to shift it from TS to JS) but it still doesn't work.

I can get the text to change on a timer easily enough, but not the fading.

Any ideas?

Using NextJS 13, built on StackBlitz's basic NextJS setup

index.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import styles from './index.module.css';

const FADE_INTERVAL_MS = 2000;
const WORD_CHANGE_INTERVAL_MS = FADE_INTERVAL_MS * 2;
const WORDS_TO_ANIMATE = [
  'Hello',
  'Ciao',
  'Jambo',
  'Bonjour',
  'Salut',
  'Hola',
  'Nǐ hǎo',
  'Hallo',
  'Hej',
  '',
];

export default function AnimatedText() {
  const [fadeProp, setFadeProp] = useState('fadeout');
  const [wordOrder, setWordOrder] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fadeTimeout = setInterval(() => {
      fadeProp === 'fadein' ? setFadeProp('fadeout') : setFadeProp('fadein');
    }, FADE_INTERVAL_MS);

    return () => clearInterval(fadeTimeout);
  }, [fadeProp]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const wordTimeout = setInterval(() => {
      setWordOrder(
        (prevWordOrder) => (prevWordOrder + 1) % WORDS_TO_ANIMATE.length
      );
    }, WORD_CHANGE_INTERVAL_MS);

    return () => clearInterval(wordTimeout);
  }, []);

  return (
    <h2 className={styles.white}>
      <span className={`styles.${fadeProp}`}>
        {WORDS_TO_ANIMATE[wordOrder]}
      </span>
      , I'm bleh.
    </h2>
  );
}
```

index.module.css

```
.fadein {
  animation: fadein 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: fadein 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 0.3s;
  -o-animation: fadein 0.3s;
}

.fadein {
  animation: fadeout 0.3s;
  -moz-animation: fadeout 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation: fadeout 0.3s;
  -o-animation: fadeout 0.3s;
}

.white {
  color: silver;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeout {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in the right path. But you need to fix a few things. Instead of doing:

```
 <span className={`styles.${fadeProp}`}>
      {WORDS_TO_ANIMATE[wordOrder]}
 </span>
```

Try it with

```
 <span className={fadeProp}>
      {WORDS_TO_ANIMATE[wordOrder]}
 </span>
```

The reason being is that you were not setting your css class name selector correclty. I think after that you can tweak it for you convenience.

------ EDIT -----

Also, you will need to create a `.css` file, not `.module.css`. I think the reason  is because the `.module.css` are compiled and cannot be dynamic.

Create a `global.css` file inside `styles` dir. Import it in you `_app.js` entrypoint inside `pages` dir.

If you do not have it, it looks something like this:
`_app.js`

```
import '../styles/globals.css';
 
// This default export is required in a new `pages/_app.js` file.
export default function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}
```

Using `globals.css` is not the best option but you can imrove that later on. Please find more info about styling Nextjs apps [here.](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/styling)